# Adding custom css files using Tailwind in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, ruby-on-rails-7

We have Tailwind working in our app, but we really want another custom css files too work for different layouts as well. So for example, I have custom1.css and custom2.css in my stylesheets folder, how can I make them work in conjunction with Tailwind?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to achieve

Comment: you mean like `@import "./custom1.css"`?

Answer (score -1):

you can add custom css inside the application.tailwind.css file e.g.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

input:invalid {
   border-color: red;
}
```

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-css-and-layer